# how to place (push) input values dynamically in stack and pop out and place in some register for display

Tags: assembly

i am trying to do 4 inputs string through user using stack procedure. but i am getting failed every time because i unable to place value in ax while pushing. i am doing pop so that i can save the previous value and make it for display. any idea for this and please also tell me where i am putting bad logic. Thanks in advance Here is the code:

```
.MODEL tiny
.data
 st1 db "Enter string$" 
 newline db 0D

.code
main proc
    mov dx, offset st1 
;   push bx 
    MOV si,0
    mov di,2 
    call fun
    mov ah,04ch
    int 21h
fun proc near
    push ax
    cmp si,4
    je exitt
    call gets
    pop ax
    mov [si],ax
    inc si
    inc di
    inc di
    call fun

exitt: ret
fun endp    






disp proc near
   ; mov dx,offset newline 
   PUSH BP
    mov bp,sp
    mov dx,[bp+2]
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h 
    POP BP
  ret
  disp endp  


gets proc near 
    PUSH BP
    mov bp,sp
    mov dx,[bp+DI]
    mov ah,0ah
    int 21h
    POP BP
    ret
    gets endp
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe If you go through this you will definately find your answer . These slides are my college notes. Very helpful in basic understanding of assembly language :)

```
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2p83odizfzi0pvv/i5Etrg68Vf/wk10-Stack.ppt

http://comp323.wordpress.com/
```

Comment: can you tell how can i place value in ax after once i "input" through "gets". i know these things.

Answer (score 0):

These instructions are in the wrong order:

```
push ax
cmp si,4
je exitt
```

When `si` equals 4 and you jump to `exitt` you never pop `ax`, so the saved value of `ax` will still be on the stack when you `ret`, thereby causing you to return to the wrong place.

You should change it to:

```
cmp si,4
je exitt
push ax
```

---

I noticed that you're using hardcoded address like `0` for storing string data. While it's possible that it will work in DOS it's generally a bad idea to write code like that. It would be better to allocate a buffer (either statically or dynamically) to hold the data.

Comment: i did that but i found another problem that is "si" after"mov [si],ax" in fun is not being increment. Any idea is that just because of stack??